# How to access standard outputs while the process is running on a computer cluster?

Tags: linux, bash, process, cluster-computing, qsub

**Intro**

I use a computer cluster on which I submit (`qsub`) jobs via a .pbs file. The default is to print standard outputs and standard errors on files in the working directory from which the `qsub` command is executed.

**Issue**

The issue for me is that the standard output and standard error files appear only at the end of the process while I would love to be able to monitor the advances of the process in direct.

**Thoughts**

I know the following options exist

```
#PBS -o
#PBS -e
#PBS -j [oe/eo]
```

in order to indicate specific file names and locations for standard outputs and standard errors. However, two points are unclear to me...

1. I don't quite know how it works when using array (via `#PBS -t`). Will standard outputs from one `PBS_ARRAYID` overwrite previous standard outputs? Do all the standard outputs for the whole array get printed on the same file or is there a way to include the `PBS_ARRAYID` in the file name?
2. Would using these options help me in any way to access the standard outputs before the end of the process?

**Question**

How can I visualize the standard outputs and standard errors before a process is over when the process is submitted on a computer cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the computer cluster I am using at least the standard outputs are kept in the RAM saved to the `#PBS -o` at the end of the process only. One way around that is to explicitly redirect the standard outputs in the shell script. Do something like:

```
executable arguments >& StandardOutputs_${PBS_JOBNAME}.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm), each task in an array job gets the environment variable `PBS_ARRAYID` set, and so you could include that in your settings:

```
#PBS -o /path/for/$PBS_JOBNAME.$PBS_ARRAYID
```

I'm not sure why your engine would be withholding the output files until the job completes.  (My grid engine doesn't do so.)  Perhaps it writes them into a temporary location or under a temporary name and then moves them when the job is done?

Comment: Thanks a lot that was already helpful +1 I ended up finding (and posting) a working solution for me.